# Break text surrounded by other elements in the same line

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to display 3 DOM elements in a row. The 1st and the 3rd ones are `div`s with constant `width` and `height`, the one in the middle is text and can grow. The height of **1** and **3** has to be equal to the height of a single line of text.

[image: Elements Arrangement]

The problem begins when the text element grows long. I'd want like to display **1** before the first line of text and **3** right where the text ends.

[image: Some other arrangement]

The combination of two changes helped me to achieve this:

1. I set `flex-wrap: wrap` for `parentContainer`

```css
.parentContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;        
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

2. I wrapped each word into its own `<span>...</span>`

[image]

Although this approach displays the elements correctly, I have two problems with it

1. Instead of using [Unicode line breaking algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/) I have to break text into words myself. The text is not guaranteed to have any whitespaces, unfortunately.
2. Double mouse click only selects text within a single span instead of the entire text.

I wonder if there is a different approach to it that isn't prone to the issues described above?

Comment: what are the elements?

Comment: They are icons, we can think of them as of `div`s with fixed width. I'll update the question

Comment: If I understand correctly, the line height of your text will have to be as high as the icon height? Or is it acceptable to have several lines next to the first icon before flowing beneath?

Comment: The height of the icon has to be equal to the height of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to achieving this might be to use css to set the display property of the icons/divs to `inline`. You may have to play with sizes to get things how you want them but making the image an inline element allows you treat it as if it were just another word.

In this example, I linked an image to simulate your bounding elements.

```css
    img {
    width: 30px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.svg" />  text text here text here more text here even more text here text here more text here even more text<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.svg" />
```

Comment: To make it work I had to delete `display: flex` from `parentContainer`. Works like a dream!